# Devise helper methods (current_user) returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After an update of HAML (from 4.0.0 to 4.0.1) I got an error on my Devise helper methods. This might trigger the error, unsure.

The Devise helper methods such as `user_signed_in?` is working (I don't have it in my view though), however the method `current_user` isn't. This error raised is `undefined method name for nil` during `current_user.name.blank?`.

This is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery


  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to items_path
  end

end
```

And this is my application view (HAML):

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Levitas secondhand
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' 
    = javascript_include_tag 'application' 
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body  
    .container
    %p{class: 'notice notice-block'}= notice
    %p{class: 'alert alert-block'}= alert

    - if signed_in?(:user)
      Ingelogd als
      %strong
    - if current_user.name.blank?
      = link_to current_user.email, current_user
    - else
      = link_to current_user.name, current_user
      |
    - if current_user.provider == nil    
      = link_to 'Account bewerken', edit_user_registration_path
      |
      = link_to "Uitloggen", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
    - else
      = link_to "Nieuwe gebruiker", new_user_registration_path
      |
      = link_to "Inloggen", new_user_session_path
      |
      = link_to "Inloggen met Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

The `current_user` returns `nil` in the live shell of better_errors, so I can image why I get the error that `name` is `nil`. But this method always worked?!

I tried to change it to `current_user.blank?` which works, but then the same error (as expected) occurs in the next line saying `email` is `nil`.

What can I do?

Comment: What it is returning? `current_user.blank?` either **true** or **false**

Comment: When using cancan you can do load_and_authorize_resource in the controller, which ensures that authentication is happening as well, are you using this helper? Because it looks like you just don't have a logged in user.

Comment: `current.user.blank?` returned **true**. And the `load_and_authorize_resource` works as well with the new indentation of the answer here beneath. This might be an answer for someone else.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's just a formatting issue with your post here but it appears you may simply have the indentation wrong? Perhaps this is what you meant?

```
- if signed_in?(:user)
  Ingelogd als
  %strong
  - if current_user.name.blank?
    = link_to current_user.email, current_user
  - else
    = link_to current_user.name, current_user
    |
  - if current_user.provider == nil    
    = link_to 'Account bewerken', edit_user_registration_path
    |
    = link_to "Uitloggen", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
- else
  = link_to "Nieuwe gebruiker", new_user_registration_path
  |
  = link_to "Inloggen", new_user_session_path
  |
  = link_to "Inloggen met Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```